# How to get all the posts of a facebook page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all the posts of a facebook page. I am following the link  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post

For example URL : http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page_id}/feed%20HTTP/1.1

I get the response as :

```
{"error": 
  {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /feed HTTP/1.1",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "Em5dm7wPr9k"
  }
}
```

I got the `page_id` from my facebook page.

Is my URL correct? Is this the correct way to get all the posts?

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=bladauhu%2Ffeed&version=v2.8

You don´t need the Page ID, but you need to get rid of the " HTTP/1.1" in the API call. It´s just `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page_id}/feed`.

Comment: But how can I use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=bladauhu%2Ffeed&version=v2.8 in Android ? Because it needs a access token. Also, where do I get access token ?

Comment: you need to start reading the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: I read the doc. So facebook login is mandatory to get the posts ?

Comment: no, you can use an app access token too if the page is not restricted in some way. but your error message is because you got the api call wrong.

Comment: Access token in a string format. But Graph Request requires token of type AccessToken. How to proceed with that? Also the access token expires after some timestamp how to to handle this at client end ?

Comment: app tokens do not expire, as you can read in the link i commented.

Comment: about the accesstoken class, please read the official docs (api reference): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/4.0/class/AccessToken/